# Atomic Integer or int[] in Recursion Question (LeetCode124)

Tags: java, recursion, atomic

So this is LeetCode Question 124
I used Java without Global variable, Why we need to use int[] or atomic but cant use int to store the max value?
What knowledge am I lacking here?

```
public int maxGain(TreeNode currNode, int[] res) {
        if(currNode == null) { return 0; }
        int leftBestSum = Math.max(maxGain(currNode.left, res), 0);
        int rightBestSum = Math.max(maxGain(currNode.right, res), 0);
        // update best result if it's better to start a new path
        int currNodeAndChildSum = currNode.val + leftBestSum + rightBestSum;
        // if currSum is better than the best result, start new path
        res[0] = Math.max(res[0], currNodeAndChildSum);
        // else if currSum is not better than the best result, pass back the best result path to
        // its parent for later compare use
        int currBestPathSum = currNode.val + Math.max(leftBestSum, rightBestSum);
        return currBestPathSum;
    }
    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        int[] res = new int[] {Integer.MIN_VALUE};
        maxGain(root, res);
        return res[0];
    }
```

Comment: Java is pass by value. In order to modify the original integer given you have to use some sort of wrapper. AtomicInteger and other integer types are valid, as is the array option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In languages with references such as C, C++, C#, PHP, Perl, etc, you can pass a pointer or reference to a value to a function and modify it in place:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doit(int *ptr_to_n) {
    *ptr_to_n = 42; // modifies the value pointed to by ptr_to_n by a dereference
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 415;
    doit(&n);
    printf(" %d\n", n); // => 42
    return 0;
}
```

Java is strictly pass-by-value and offers no pointers or address-of operators. The code you've presented here abuses an array to overcome this restriction. In the below code, the reference to the array in the calling scope is copied and passed by value to `res`, but `res` still points to the same underlying object as `arr`, so the array itself is not copied, only aliased.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 415;
        int[] arr = {415};
        doit(n);
        doitPointer(arr);

        System.out.println("Copy primitive: " + n);
        System.out.println("Copy reference to object: " + arr[0]);
    }

    static void doit(int n) {
        n = 42; // assignment to local variable which will be unavailable in outer scope
    }

    static void doitPointer(int[] res) {
        res[0] = 42; // assignment to element in referenced array, available in outer scope
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Copy primitive: 415
Copy reference to object: 42
```

In competitive programming, this is a useful and acceptable technique that can simplify logic, but typically this is lazy practice in a production setting because it breaks encapsulation, makes the code difficult to reason about and has a semantic cost.

Use a class to encapsulate the value, put the functions in a scope such that they can modify private class members, or rewrite the logic to avoid the need for references.

Answer (score 0):

This is really hacky. You're attempting to hack this solution to allow output parameters by using a container as an input variable. You're putting it in a container to avoid the pass by value nature of integers which would copy the parameter to the function.

Instead, why not just return multiple values?

```
/**
 * Return an array containing the overall nodes 
 * maximum height and the overall max gain.
 **/
public int[] maxGain(TreeNode currNode) {
    if (currNode == null) {
        return new int[] { 0, Integer.MIN_VALUE };
    }

    int[] leftResult = maxGain(currNode.left);
    int[] rightResult = maxGain(currNode.right);

    int maxHeight = Math.max(leftResult[0], rightResult[0]) + currNode.val;

    int currGain = leftResult[0] + rightResult[0] + currNode.val;

    int maxGain = Math.max(currGain, Math.max(leftResult[1], rightResult[1]));

    return new int[] { maxHeight, maxGain };
}

public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
    int[] result = maxGain(root);
    return result[1];
}
```